# CSS to change the border style of a span depending on whether it's in the first LINE of it's parent block element

Tags: css, codemirror, adobe-brackets

### Prologue

I have a layout that looks somewhat like this:
[image]

Here it is on ["JSFiddle"](http://jsfiddle.net/vqZdK/40/).

The DIV that it's all about, looks like this and is displayed below a line of text:

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <span class="offset" style="width: 150px">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="myText">First: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="offset" style="width: 500px">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="myText">Second: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="offset" style="width: 50px">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="myText">Third: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="offset" style="width: 233px">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="myText">Fourth: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

#### Idea

Use the read error spans to highlight errors in the text above. The error-spans are placed in such a way that their top-left corner points to the character position in the text where the error appeared. I use spans (colored yellow) here in front of the actual error spans (red) to move the error spans to the right by the correct amount. (It's not a nice way, I'll explain why below in case you are interested and I'm open for recommendations, but that's not the current problem)

This way, I was able to make the spans start at a specific position from the left but wrap around if there is not enough space and continue at the start of the line. If there is not enough space (due to the offset) for even a single word the complete span moves to the next line. This is the behaviour I want.

## Problem

When the spans move to the next line completely due to a lack of space on the right their "pointy" corner on the top-left is no longer correct. In that case I would like to make the span have rounded corners all around. But I could not find a way to do it.
I want to avoid using Javascript/jquery for it, because it seems like a lot of cumbersome calculations and I would have to recalculate it whenever the containing window or even div is resized.

#### Tried so far

I mainly looked at the CSS pseudo-element `:first-line` since it sounds like what I want to have. But the [spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#selector-syntax) that the `:first-line` element has to be the last selector in a list of selectors. I tried it and indeed

```
div:first-line .myText {
    # apply some layout
}
```

doesn't work.

Neither does

```
.myText:first-line {
    # apply some layout
}
```

since the :`first-line` element [can only be attached to block container elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-line-pseudo).

It would work if I made .myText an `inline-block` element, but that causes it to wrap to early (if it doesn't fit in the first line completely). `display:block` just makes the early-wrapping worse (directly starts at the next line).

And I can't just select `div:first-line` since

1. `:first-line` [doesn't allow to set the border](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-line-pseudo).
2. Even if it did, it would modify the border around the :first-line block element, which wouldn't change the border of the span inside it.

*Any ideas how I can make the top-left corner of the span round if it is in the second line of the div without writing a lot of Javascript-code trying to find out whether the span has moved to the next line completely and registering a resize listener to recalculate it everytime?*

#### Why use offset spans instead of `margin-left:200px` or `position:relative; left:200px`?

Both caused the container div to grow and I can't have that. This layout is embedded in a scroll-view, much like the preview on JSFiddle. Try setting the `.offset` spans to `display:none` and the `.myText` span's margin-left to something big (e.g. 500px), then resize the JSFiddle preview until all of the line wraps around to the next line (except for the first word of the span). The first word will always be on the first line and thus cause the container div to be bigger than it would otherwise be. In my case the container div does not even resize which causes the text to be cut off.

Thus, I use another span in front, with a custom width (determined by Javascript/jquery depending on the position of the error). This way the complete span can wrap to the next line if there is not enough space on the first (in that case, it starts at the beginning of the line, as you can see in the span starting with "Second").

#### Context

It's for an extension for [Adobe Brackets](https://github.com/adobe/brackets), I'm using the addLineWidget() method of the CodeMirror editor inside it to inject the div with the error messages. So anything making use of Brackets/CodeMirror APIs to solve the problem would be fine as well.

Comment: The reference for pseudo-elements being the last in a selector can be found in [this section](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#selector-syntax) of the spec. To be exact, only the subject of a selector can have a pseudo-element; up to and including [Selectors 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors), the subject of a selector is always the rightmost part.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I remember reading it, but couldn't find it again. :-)